# How can I get an image title and set the title attribute using wp_get_attachment_image and ACF Image fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields image field, returning an ID.

The documentation says that when using the image ID, you use the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function to generate the image HTML, but despite following the advice for that I cannot seem to get the title and I don't know why.

I have tried various things including the following:

```
if( get_field('pre-defined_block_choice') == 'weddings' ) {

    $image = get_field('wedding_image_1');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $title = $image['title'];
    
       if( $image ) {
          echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, $title );
       }
}
```

And

```
if( get_field('pre-defined_block_choice') == 'weddings' ) {

    $image = get_field('wedding_image_1');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $attachment_title = get_the_title($attach_id);
    
       if( $image ) {
          echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, $attachment_title );
       }
}
```

This returns the `srcset`, `alt` attributes and `class` names but not the `title`. How do I also get it to return the title?

Comment: You said yourself that you had your ACF field configured to return the ID only - so what sense is `$image['title']` supposed to make then?

Comment: And the third parameter for `wp_get_attachment_image` is `$icon`, a boolean that determines whether the image should be treated as an icon or not. Passing a `$title` or `$attachment_title` for that probably doesn’t make that much sense either.

Comment: Using image ID still allows you to return other parameters, currently it returns ALL but the title. The two attempts that I used are pulled from the ACF and Wordpress documentation. I'm unsure where $icon comes into it?

Comment: These ACF image fields allow you to either return an array/object with image data, the image URL, or _just_ the ID. I assumed you meant the latter here, of course.

Comment: _“I'm unsure where $icon comes into it?”_ - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Comment: As CBroe says, it doesn't make sense that you have the ACF field set to return only the Image ID but you say you are also getting other information returned. Please show us your settings for this field so we can understand exactly what you have. (A screen shot of the field in the ACF Group page would suffice)

Comment: @CBroe By default, mine seems to return the srcset and alt parameters without me calling it. Maybe I am missing something here but I understand what $icon is, I'm just not sure where it comes in because I am not asking for that particular paramater in my code?

Comment: @FluffyKitten will this suffice? Thanks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uw4zz0hapr0h9gk/Screenshot%202020-07-25%20at%2011.54.52.png?dl=0

Comment: Your ACF field is only returning the ID as we suspected. Are you getting mixed up about return values and parameters? For example you say that `wp_get_attachment_image` returnd the srcset, alt etc... but the function *accepts* these values as parameters and *returns* the HTML? Or do you mean that the HTML contains these values but not the title? I've added an answer below based on what I think you are looking for based on your comments (and on what is possible!) - let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm so sorry for the delay in getting back to you - these both seem to work!. I am using the second version as I would like to utilise srcset - thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments it looks like you are trying to get the image title from the title added in the Media Gallery and/or set the title attribute for the image when it is displayed on the website.

There are 2 ways you can get and set the title of the image:

1. **Change the ACF field to return an "Image Array"** instead of the "Image ID" (This appears to be what you are trying in your first example in your question).
2. **Use WP functions to get and/or set the image title** using the image ID (This appears to be what you are trying in your second example).

I'll show you below how to get both working:

**1. Get the "Image Array" with all the image details from your ACF field**

The image title is returned in the array so you don't need to use additional functions to then look up the image details (including the title) using the id. You also build the image HTML in your code so you can add the title as required.

First you need to change the ACF field settings and choose "Image Array" as the "Return Format". Then you can use the following code:

```
if( get_field('pre-defined_block_choice') == 'weddings' ) {

    $image = get_field('wedding_image_1');
    if( $image ){
        // 1. Get the values we need from the image array
        $url   = $image['url'];
        $alt   = $image['alt'];
        $title = $image['title'];        // <- the TITLE!
        $id    = $image['ID']; // We don't need it here, but this is how you get it
        $width = $image['width'];
        $height = $image['height'];

        // 2. If you want an image a particular size
        $size = "thumb"; // or whatever size you want
        $thumb_url = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
        // First make sure the size you want exists and if so, get the width & height
        if ($thumb_url){
            $url = $thumb_url; // set our url variable to this one url if it exists
            $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
            $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];
        }
    
        // 3. Now build your image HTML
        $img_html = '<img src="'.$url.'" title = "'.$title.'" alt="'.$alt.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">';

        // 4. do whatever you want with the image e.g. return it or display it
        echo $img_html;
    }
}
```

**2. Use the image ID to get and set the image details (including the title) using WP functions**

This way, you don't change the ACF field settings, but you need to use multiple WP functions to get and set the details of the image.

Note that `wp_get_attachment_image` doesn't have an option to pass in the title attribute for the image according to the documentation... however **if you pass the title into wp_get_attachment_image in the $attr array, it seems to work!** (Of course there is no guarantee that this will continue to work in newer version of WP).

```
if( get_field('pre-defined_block_choice') == 'weddings' ) {

    $image_id = get_field('wedding_image_1');
    if( $image_id ) {
        $size = 'full'; // or whatever size you want    
        $title = get_the_title( $image_id );  // 1. NOTE: use image ID here, you have no $attach_id!

        // 2. set up your attributes array to pass in the title
        $attr['title'] = $title;

        // 3. Take note of the parameters for this you were passing values in the wrong positions
       $img_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size, false, $attr);

        // 4. do whatever you want with the image e.g. return it or display it
        echo $img_html;
    }
}
```

*(Note: This code is untested, but the general idea is there.)*

**References**

- [ACF Image field documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)
- [wp_get_attachment_image WP Function Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)
- ["Set title attribute..." in question on Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294838/set-title-attribute-in-wp-get-attachment-image)